# How to test December month of this?

Tags: python, tdd

```
def due_date(days: int) -> datetime:
    if days == 30:
        return datetime.now()+ relativedelta(months=1)
    elif days == 60:
        return datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=2)
    elif days == 90:
        return datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=3)
    else:
        return datetime.now()
```

I am worry on 20 December 2017. That my output may return an incorrect answer. I had asked my issue https://github.com/spulec/freezegun/issues/171

**Python: 3.6.0**
**pytest: 3.0.5**
**freezegun: 0.3.8**

Comment: Actually I tested this with Python3.6 and it works (your example in github)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with Python3.6 and it worked:

```
In [1]: import datetime
   ...: from freezegun import freeze_time
   ...: 

In [2]: with freeze_time('2018-01-01'):
   ...:     print(datetime.datetime.now())
   ...: 
2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

What version of freezegun you use ? I use 0.3.8

Comment: I have same result with you. I am thinking `pytest` may be the issue

Comment: pytest cdmop/apps/invoices/tests.py